# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Chris/Downloads/kaggle_original_data\\cat.0.jpg'

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I´m using TensorFlow 2.3.1 (Python 3.8, in Anaconda) on a Windows10 system. I try to run a machine learning script and have some trouble with storing my data. I assume it has something to do with the slash / backslash differences in Unix/Windows? Can anybody please give me a hint to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
# The path to the directory where the original
# dataset was uncompressed
original_dataset_dir = '/Users/Chris/Downloads/kaggle_original_data'

# The directory where we will
# store our smaller dataset
base_dir = '/Users/Chris/Downloads/cats_and_dogs_small'
os.mkdir(base_dir)

# Directories for our training,
# validation and test splits
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
os.mkdir(train_dir)
validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'validation')
os.mkdir(validation_dir)
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test')
os.mkdir(test_dir)

# Directory with our training cat pictures
train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(train_cats_dir)

# Directory with our training dog pictures
train_dogs_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'dogs')
os.mkdir(train_dogs_dir)

# Directory with our validation cat pictures
validation_cats_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(validation_cats_dir)

# Directory with our validation dog pictures
validation_dogs_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'dogs')
os.mkdir(validation_dogs_dir)

# Directory with our validation cat pictures
test_cats_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(test_cats_dir)

# Directory with our validation dog pictures
test_dogs_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'dogs')
os.mkdir(test_dogs_dir)

# Copy first 1000 cat images to train_cats_dir
fnames = ['cat.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dataset_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(train_cats_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

# Copy next 500 cat images to validation_cats_dir
fnames = ['cat.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000, 1500)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dataset_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(validation_cats_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
    
# Copy next 500 cat images to test_cats_dir
fnames = ['cat.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1500, 2000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dataset_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(test_cats_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
    
# Copy first 1000 dog images to train_dogs_dir
fnames = ['dog.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dataset_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(train_dogs_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
    
# Copy next 500 dog images to validation_dogs_dir
fnames = ['dog.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000, 1500)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dataset_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(validation_dogs_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
    
# Copy next 500 dog images to test_dogs_dir
fnames = ['dog.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1500, 2000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dataset_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(test_dogs_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux uses forward slashes for paths, and Windows uses backslashes

However, backslash is Python's escape character so you actually have to double them up when working with paths

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Python37'
```

You are setting your paths for **original_dataset_dir** and **base_dir** in a Linux format, whereas they should be something like this: **'C:\\Users\\Chris\\Downloads\\kaggle_original_data'**

Comment: ```# The path to the directory where the original
# dataset was uncompressed
original_dataset_dir = 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\Downloads\\kaggle_original_data'

# The directory where we will
# store our smaller dataset
base_dir = 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\Downloads\\cats_and_dogs_small'
os.mkdir(base_dir) ``` I tryed this but it doesn`t work...

Comment: @Chris - Is the error still the same? Could you post the error, and the properties of the file that you're trying to copy so I can see the full path?

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\Downloads\\kaggle_original_data\\cat.0.jpg'

Comment: properties: e.g. "cat.1501.jpg" as a work around i copied the data manualy but it would be interesting why it doesn`t work by the script.

Comment: @Chris does **cat.0.jpg** exist in that directory given that's that one that's throwing the error for you? You just gave the example **cat.1501.jpg**, but that wouldn't be until the third range of executions

Comment: Thank´s for your precious hints, i made a simple failure and forgot to add an sub folder in the "original_dataset_dir - line" in which the pictures were stored... sorry. Now everthing works fine. Again many thanks...

Comment: @Chris - you're welcome mate! If this helped, please mark as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `os.path.abspath` on `original_dataset_dir` and `base_dir`

```
original_dataset_dir = os.path.abspath(original_dataset_dir)
base_dir = os.path.abspath(base_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, shutil 


original_dataset_dir = 'C:\\Users\\Aga\\Downloads\\kagglecatsanddogs_5340\\PetImages'
cat_dir = original_dataset_dir + '\\Cat'
dog_dir = original_dataset_dir + '\\Dog'


base_dir='C:\\Users\\Aga\\Downloads\\cats_and_dogs_small'
os.mkdir(base_dir)


train_dir=os.path.join(base_dir, 'train') #eğitim setinin dizini
os.mkdir(train_dir)

validation_dir=os.path.join(base_dir, 'validation') 
os.mkdir(validation_dir)

test_dir=os.path.join(base_dir, 'test') 
os.mkdir(test_dir)

train_cats_dir=os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(train_cats_dir)

train_dogs_dir= os.path.join(train_dir, 'dogs') 
os.mkdir(train_dogs_dir)

validation_cats_dir=os.path.join(validation_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(validation_cats_dir)

validation_dogs_dir=os.path.join(validation_dir, 'dogs')
os.mkdir(validation_dogs_dir)

test_cats_dir=os.path.join(test_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(test_cats_dir)

test_dogs_dir=os.path.join(test_dir, 'dogs')
os.mkdir(test_dogs_dir)

fnames = ['{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(cat_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(train_cats_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

fnames =['{}.jpg'. format(i) for i in range (1000, 1500)]
for fname in fnames:
    src=os.path.join(cat_dir, fname)
    dst=os.path.join(validation_cats_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src,dst)    
    
fnames =['{}.jpg'. format(i) for i in range (1500, 2000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src=os.path.join(cat_dir, fname)
    dst=os.path.join(test_cats_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src,dst)    
    
    
fnames =['{}.jpg'. format(i) for i in range (1000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src=os.path.join(dog_dir, fname)
    dst=os.path.join(train_dogs_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src,dst)
    
fnames =['{}.jpg'. format(i) for i in range (1000, 1500)]
for fname in fnames:
    src=os.path.join(dog_dir, fname)
    dst=os.path.join(validation_dogs_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src,dst)    
    
fnames =['{}.jpg'. format(i) for i in range (1500, 2000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src=os.path.join(dog_dir, fname)
    dst=os.path.join(test_dogs_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src,dst)    


#hi, this is how i solved the problem.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).